# Host works fine with other monitors, monitor works fine with other hosts - but not each other

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I've been trying to characterize and troubleshoot a monitor problem.

Consider:
Monitor A (NEC 1980SX)
Monitor B (Acer AL2416W)
Host A (HP Xeon PC w/ Win7 64bit)
Host B (Macbook Pro 2012 w/ OS X 10.10)
Host C (Macbook Pro 2010 w/ 10.8)

- Host A works with Monitor A perfectly, over both VGA and DVI
- Host A works with Monitor B perfectly, over both VGA and DVI
- Host B works with Monitor A perfectly, over both VGA and DVI
- Host B doesn't work with Monitor B at all. Over DVI the monitor reports "no signal" as if nothing is connected, over VGA the monitor and host behave happily as if everything is connected correctly, but the screen is completely black.

As it happens, host B with monitor B is my most important and day-to-day configuration...

Some more history:

- Used to run Host C with monitor B. It would be a bit finicky sometimes, requiring a reboot to recognize the monitor, but otherwise worked.
- In 2014 monitor B decided to die and wouldn't turn on. I opened it up, reseated the boards, and it came back to life.
- 2 months ago I switched to a newer MBP (host B). From that moment, monitor B started behaving as described above. But, it doesn't even work with host C anymore!

Testing the different configurations, and with multiple cables, took the possibility of bad cables out of the equation. Neither monitor has other ports to test. I also tried multiple reboots, power cycles, letting it "sit" overnight, etc.

What can cause a certain host/GPU to not work with a certain monitor?